# C - Mysterious Segmentation Fault with Threading

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, segmentation-fault

this is a simple program I've been working on that listens to a socket, and starts a new thread to handle each connection to said socket. 
In my while loop I get a Segmentation Fault, that has something to do with `pthread_create` (if I comment that line out the program loops properly). My knowledge of pointers is mediocre at best, and debugging with gdb didn't yield anything of value. This is gdb's output:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000080064f4f1 in pthread_getprio () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Error accessing memory address 0x7fffffbff000: Bad address.
```

The program gets through the while loop once successfully, and properly receives and responds to a connection at the socket, but then before getting into the second while loop, the program fails on a Segmentation Fault error.

Here's a condensed version of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define UNIX_PATH_MAX 100
#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/demo_socket"

/*===============> CONNECTION HANDLER FUNCTION <=================*/
void *connection_handler(int connection_fd)
{
    int nbytes;
    char buffer[256];

nbytes = read(connection_fd, buffer, 256); 
buffer[nbytes] = 0;
printf("\tMESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);

nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256, "Hello from the server!");
write(connection_fd, buffer, nbytes);

close(connection_fd);

return;
}


/*==========================> MAIN <=============================*/
int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr; //socket address information
    int sock_fd, conn_fd; //socket file descriptors
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un); //size of sockaddr_un structure
    pid_t child_pid; //pid holder
    pthread_t thread; // thread identifier 


sock_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sock_fd < 0)
    return 1;
unlink(SOCK_PATH);



memset(&addr, 0, addr_len); 

addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1); // Copies up to sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1 bytes from SOCK_PATH into addr.sun_path 
printf("> Socket sun_family = %d (AF_UNIX), Socket sun_path = %s ...\n", addr.sun_family, addr.sun_path);


/*----------------------FAIL CHECKS-------------------------*/
if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addr_len) != 0) 
    return 1;
if (listen(sock_fd, 5) != 0)
    return 1;

printf("> Listening to socket bound at %s ...\n\n", SOCK_PATH);


/*--------------------WHILE LOOP----------------------------*/
while ( (conn_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len)) > -1) {

    pthread_create(&thread , NULL, connection_handler(conn_fd), NULL); 

    printf("> Closing connection at %d inside server process ...\n", conn_fd);
    close(conn_fd);
    printf("> Reached bottom of loop!\n");
    }


/*---------------------------FIN------------------------------*/
close(sock_fd);
unlink(SOCK_PATH);
printf("> Socket closed and unlinked from path ... Done!\n ");
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a complete aside, you probably don't want to close `conn_fd` right after you create your thread. let the thread deal with closing its connection (unless `pthread_create` fails)

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
pthread_create(&thread , NULL, connection_handler(conn_fd), NULL);
```

`pthread_create` requires the address of the function to run in the new thread. What your code does is call `connection_handler` in the main thread and then pass **the result of `connection_handler`** to pthread_create as the function address.

What you need is the following:

```
pthread_create(&thread , NULL, connection_handler, (void*)conn_fd);
```

You'll also need to change `connection_handler` to take `void*` instead of `int`:

```
void *connection_handler(void* arg)
{
  intptr_t connection_fd = (intptr_t)arg;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why does this compile? that parameter is a function pointer `void *(*__start_routine) (void *)`

Comment: Ahhh wunderbar! This works, I figured it was my amateur knowledge of threading that was leading to the segfault error. Thanks much! However I think it should be &connection_handler in the pthread_create() call.

Comment: @C_p678 22: You're welcome. BTW, the `&` in `&connection_handler` is optional - see http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx10a.html

Comment: @aix: If you pass a pointer to the argument, make sure that the value is taken by the thread before it is changed. this will most likely require some minor synchronization between the threads.

Comment: `&conn_fd` **will not work**. It has a very bad race condition and will be modified before the new thread can read it. Instead you need `(void *)conn_fd` or some more elaborate way to pass it.

Comment: @R..: Can you explain how (void*)conn_fd avoids a race condition? Doesn't that still just send the address of conn_fd to the thread the same way as &conn_fd would?

Comment: @C_p678: No, it doesn't. I sends **the value** of `conn_fd` disguised as a pointer.

Comment: No. It casts the integer to a pointer in order to pass it by value. Without an `&` operator there is no possibility of obtaining the address of `conn_fd`.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `pthread_create` is incorrect. the third argument should be a pointer to a function of type `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`, instead you are passing the return of `connection_handler`.

Change `connection_handler` to receive a `void *` argument (and make sure it returns an actual value), eg.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void *connection_handler(void *arg)
{
    intptr_t connection_fd = (intptr_t)arg;
    ...
    return NULL;
}
```

and change your call to something like the following

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &connection_handler, (void *)conn_fd);
```

You should also make sure to either start the thread detached, detach the thread with `pthread_detach` or join it later with `pthread_join`

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but I get this error:
warning: passing argument 4 of 'pthread_create' makes pointer from integer without a cast....

Comment: @C_p678: Sorry, that should have been `(void *)`, not `intptr_t`. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer[nbytes] = 0;
```

This will overflow if you've read 256 bytes. Increase buffer size or decrease read size by one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not the problem, The message I'm sending is just "Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are closing the socket connection in two places. There is good chance that in one run of the thread its not yet got around to the `write` but in your parent thread already closed the connection.

Why do you need to create so many threads? Wouldn't one worker thread suffice? you can pile up the jobs on to this worker thread...

Comment: Well the socket potentially could be getting multiple connections in a very short time span, so I figured creating a thread per connection would be the best route to take. As opposed to a process per connection.

Comment: how long do you think the thread will run for? I mean you are just reading and writing 256 bytes.. It should be quite fast so by queueing up the jobs you should not see any difference.

Comment: This is just a skeleton, the thread will search the received message for certain keywords, check the time it was sent, etc. So it could take some time.